# RPKI in the Enterprise

Tags: bgp

What is the concensus on the use case for RPKI? Is it useful for a stub AS to perform route validation or is this better left to the providers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RPKI is two-way action. First of all, it would be nice if you could sign your own prefixes, so nobody will be able to hijack them somewhere in the other part of the internet (if his upstreams support and validate prefix advertisements using RPKI). The more end-sites will use RPKI, the better value will have using RPKI to various SPs and more SPs will do it.

On the SP side, it would be beneficial to push your upstreams to implement RPKI at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

This is really an opinion question; however, I'd say you'd rather have it and not need it than need it and not have it.

I don't trust anything outside of my AS.

That sounded funny.

But really, you can't assume your upstream is doing their job correctly.